# Flip the Y axis?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, coordinates

The way coordinates are at the moment for cocoa touch is in the upper left corner it's 0,0. What I'm wondering is if it's possible to sort of "flip" it so the 0,0 is in the bottom left corner?

I want the coordinating system to be like cocos2d were the 0,0 point is in the bottom left corner. Is it possible to make that happen in cocoa touch?

Comment: Please provide some more context: are you drawing your own content using `CG...` routines? How the rotation should play into this, or should rotation be considered at all? [This topic may be relevant](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html), depending on what you are doing.

Comment: I want it to be like in Cocos2d were the y 0 point is at the bottom and not in the top of the screen. And why did you downvote? makes no sence

Comment: What makes you think that I downvoted your question? I don't think it's clear, but I also don't think it's bad enough to be downvoted.

Comment: Well you are the only one commenting so I thought it was you :S sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: You may want to explain what you want to happen, mentioning Cocos2d, and any interoperability with it, if that is what you would like to happen. An edit would at least give whomever downvoted an opportunity to retract his/her vote.

Answer (score 4):

You asked the question about “Cocoa”, but, in fact, Cocoa has had a highly visible distinction between flipped and unflipped views for a long time. In Cocoa, you would simply need to [override a method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/isFlipped). (And “flipped” in Cocoa means the way Cocoa Touch does it. The default—“unflipped”—in Cocoa is lower-left origin.)

But you're not programming Cocoa; you're programming Cocoa Touch.

So, you have a context that is flipped, presumably because you got it from UIKit (CGContexts that you create without going through UIKit are unflipped), and you need to unflip it. (Or you have an unflipped context and want to flip it.)

Either way, the solution is the same:

1. Translate up/down (positive y) by the entire height of the context/view.
2. Scale the y axis by -1.

Translation moves the origin; translating by the entire height moves the origin to the opposite corner.

Scaling changes the axes; scaling the y axis by negative 1 flips it in the opposite direction, so what was up is now down and vice versa.

That is how you flip (or unflip) a context from upper-left origin to lower-left or vice versa.

Things that will not work or otherwise should not be tried:

- Setting `geometryFlipped` on the layer. It affects sublayers, but not custom drawing. (Of course, if all of your “drawing” is shape layers and text layers and plain layers, then you can just set this property and not worry about transforms.)
- Overriding `contentsAreFlipped` in a CALayer subclass. The documentation says not to do that.
- Setting the view's or its layer's `transform`. The documentation says that the coordinate space that `transform` is applied to has the origin in the center (or at `anchorPoint`), not in a corner. It's tempting, but I would expect hilarity to ensue.